# Change Log NULL records in CMIS Workbench - SharePoint 2013 SP1

Tags: .net, cmis, opencmis, dotcmis, cmis-workbench

## Change Log show null records when using AtomPub

I am using [CMIS Workbench 0.13.0](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) to connect to a SharePoint 2013 server (SP1) via:

## AtomPub endpoint

i.e. `http://<host>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories`
[image]

## Web Service endpoint

i.e. `http://<host>/_vti_bin/cmissoapwsdl.aspx`
[image]

## [DotCMIS 0.7](https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) (similiar problem)

`session.GetContentChanges(token, True, 1000).ChangeEventList`

`[1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM] Created`

`[1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM] Created`

`[1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM] Created`
`...`

## Postman (GET) of change log endpoint returns valid results

sample of: `http://<host>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repo-guid>?getContentChanges&changeLogToken=1;3;<repo-guid>;635919759698870000;11627;02/25/2016 05:46:10&includeProperties=true&includePolicyIds=false&includeACL=false&maxItems=1000`

```
<object xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/">
    <properties xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
        &lt;propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId" localName="cmis:objectId" displayName="cmis:objectId" queryName="cmis:objectId" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;129&lt;/value&gt;
        &lt;/propertyId&gt;
        &lt;propertyId propertyDefinitionId="SiteId" localName="SiteId" displayName="SiteId" queryName="SiteId" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;(item-guid)&lt;/value&gt;
        &lt;/propertyId&gt;
        &lt;propertyString propertyDefinitionId="ChangeToken" localName="ChangeToken" displayName="ChangeToken" queryName="ChangeToken" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1;3;(repo-guid);635919759698870000;11627;02/25/2016 05:46:10&lt;/value&gt;
        &lt;/propertyString&gt;
        &lt;propertyString propertyDefinitionId="ChangeType" localName="ChangeType" displayName="ChangeType" queryName="ChangeType" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;Add&lt;/value&gt;
        &lt;/propertyString&gt;
        &lt;propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="Time" localName="Time" displayName="Time" queryName="Time" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2016-02-25T05:46:10Z&lt;/value&gt;
        &lt;/propertyDateTime&gt;
    </properties>
    <changeEventInfo xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
        &lt;changeType xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;created&lt;/changeType&gt;
        &lt;changeTime xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"&gt;2016-02-25T05:46:10Z&lt;/changeTime&gt;
    </changeEventInfo>
</object>
```

Comment: Do you have the SharePoint CU February 2016 installed? Microsoft delivered CMIS related few bug fixes with this update.

Comment: Thank you, the update fixed the change log bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed by patching SharePoint 2013 SP1 with the Feb 2016 SharePoint Cumulative Update (CU) from Microsoft.

- [CU for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB3114726)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114726)
- Pre-requisite of this CU is [SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2880552)

Thank you Florian!